# JPA2: Using TemporalType=TIMESTAMP as part in a composite primary key

Tags: jpa-2.0

In the JavaEE 6 tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqf) the following is stated regarding how to map primary keys:

> The primary key, or the property or field of a composite primary key, must be one of the following Java language types:
>   --cut--
>   
> java.util.Date (the temporal type should be DATE)
>   
> --cut--

What does it mean when it is written "should be DATE"? What are the implications of using TemporalType=TIMESTAMP?

I have a composite primary key which has two fields, a long and a java.util.Date.
In the entity I have the following mapping (not listing the ID-class):

```
@Id
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startDate;

@Id
private long id;
```

The above works fine in the unit tests, but I am concerned about the wording above regarding which temporal type to use.

Comments and insights are appreciated!